# jquery function not working correctly in click event

Tags: jquery, ajax, function, events, click

I have a function called server

```
 function server(){
  return ajax();
 }
```

When the click event is called

```
 $("button").click(function(){
 var self = $(this);
 self.html('<span>Loading</span>');
 server({
 url:url,
 success: function(){
 self.html('Click Me');
 }
 });
 });
```

In Firefox Browser `Button` html set `Loading text` and works well server function

But
In Chrome Browser `Button` html not change Of course works well server function

What could be the reason?

**EDIT : (more info)**

In server function set Button html after `success` or `error` status

```
 function server(options){
  return ajax({
  user: options.url,
 success: function(){
 options.success();
 }
```

});
}

Answer (score 0):

Checked like below, Its working as expected in both browser chrome & firefox :

```
    //HTML
    
    <button>clickMe</button>
    
    //JS
<script>
        function server(url){
          console.log('called',url);
         }
         
         $("button").click(function(){
            var url = "https://google.com"
             var self = $(this);
             self.html('<span>Loading</span>');
             server(url);
         });
</script>
```